# Error when trying to update Mono (no Release file on CD)

Tags: mono

From Mono v4.6.2 on Debian v9.5 (with Debian install CD in the drive)

After adding the correct repositories for Debian 9 (following instructions at https://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/#download-lin-debian):

**`apt update`**

```
Ign:1 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 xfce-CD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch InRelease
Err:2 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 xfce-CD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch Release
Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update can not be used to add new CD-ROMs
Ign:3 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease
Hit:4 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates InRelease
Hit:5 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian stretch-updates InRelease
Hit:6 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian stretch Release
Hit:7 http://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable InRelease
Hit:9 http://linux.teamviewer.com/deb preview InRelease
Hit:10 https://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian stable-stretch InRelease
Ign:8 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian jessie InRelease
Hit:11 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian jessie Release
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 xfce-CD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I tried:

**`apt-cdrom add`**

```
Using CD-ROM mount point /media/cdrom/
Unmounting CD-ROM...
Waiting for disc...
Please insert a Disc in the drive and press [Enter]
Mounting CD-ROM...
Identifying... [411e6cc38c8dd1371217e68c34e1ecd0-2]
Scanning disc for index files...
Found 1 package indexes, 0 source indexes, 1 translation indexes and 0 signaturs
This disc is called:
'Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 xfce-CD Binary-1 20180714-10:25'
Reading Package Indexes... Done
Reading Translation Indexes... Done
Writing new source list
Source list entries for this disc are:
deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 xfce-CD Binary-1 20180714-10:25]/ stretch main
Unmounting CD-ROM...
Repeat this process for the rest of the CDs in your set.
```

But I still get the same error with **`apt update`**.

OK, ejected CD from drive (per Lex Li).  In the meantime I have discovered that I need to pin my repo package to v5.0.1, so have modified the update instructions to the following:

```
echo "deb download.mono-project.com/repo/debian stable-stretch/snapshots/5.0.1 main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-official-stable.list
```

then re-run **`apt update`**

But am getting this output:

```
Ign:1 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 xfce-CD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch InRelease
Err:2 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 xfce-CD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch Release
Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
Hit:3 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates InRelease
Ign:4 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease
Hit:5 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian stretch-updates InRelease
Hit:6 http://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable InRelease
Hit:7 http://linux.teamviewer.com/deb preview InRelease
Hit:9 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian stretch Release
Ign:8 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian jessie InRelease
Hit:10 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian jessie Release
Ign:11 https://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian stable-stretch/snapshots/5.0.1 InRelease
Err:12 https://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian stable-stretch/snapshots/5.0.1 Release
404  Not Found
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 xfce-CD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'https://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian stable-stretch/snapshots/5.0.1 Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: What you should do is to use the latest, https://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/#download-lin-debian 4.x is too old.

Comment: That is exactly what I did.  Where do you see any references to Mono v4.x ?

Comment: You'd better remove the CD rom from your apt repo list. Then via the internet you can update your system.